# Swift - Programmatically Change Constraints

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, constraints

I am trying to 'show' & 'hide' a collection view by manipulating the constraints programmatically.

My app is written in code, no storyboards or @IBOutlets are being used.

The first time I press the button, the collection view appears correctly and as expected.

The second time I press the button, the collection view just stays in place and does not 'hide'.

The print statements within the `openMenu` code are confirming that each block of constraints is being called.  ie: I get console messages for 'open' and 'closed'.

I don't have an issue with creating the collection view, it's just that setting the constraints programmatically does not close the menu.

My code is as follows...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(bgImageView)

    view.addSubview(myListCV)
}

lazy var myListCV: UICollectionView = {

    let myListLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    myListLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)
    myListLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    myListLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

    let myListView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: myListLayout)
    myListView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myListView.delegate = self
    myListView.dataSource = self

    myListView.bounces = false
    myListView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    myListView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    myListView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 203, g: 203, b: 203)

    return myListView
}()

var menuShowing = false

func openMenu() {

    if (menuShowing) {
        print("closed")
        myListCV.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        myListCV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 64).isActive = true
        myListCV.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        myListCV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    } else {
        print("open")
        myListCV.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
        myListCV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 64).isActive = true
        myListCV.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        myListCV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    menuShowing = !menuShowing
}
```

Comment: Use the View Debugger!

Comment: You should be **activating/deactivating** constraints, not simply setting things as `isActive = true`. Consider - the `rightAnchor` constraint is set *twice*, depending on the `if` statement! How does make logical sense? Either (a) group your constraints into array and *activate/deactivate* them, or (b) declare *by variable name* the constraints you wish to change and *then* change them in your if statement.

Comment: @matt thanks for your input.  If by "Use the View Debugger!" you mean place breakpoints and step through the code, I have done that.    I can see that I am setting two left anchor constraints, which may be stopping the collection view from closing.  I believed that the 'if' statement would only set what was asked based on the condition.  Can you provide any comments that would help me fix this issue?

Comment: @dfd Thanks, I will look into declaring via a variable and only change the one I need to 'hide' the collection view.  Once the constant of the constraint is changed, should it take effect immediately?  ie: without reloading the view.

Comment: The view debugger shows you your views. And your constraints. And it reveals constraint problems. It will explain everything instantly

Comment: @matt Thank you for your guidance of the view debugger.  I've never used it before and it came in handy to get a visual on what was happening.  As per the accepted answer, my issue is resolved and I used the view debugger to prove that only the constraints I wanted were being set.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for reporting back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your above code is that you are continually setting constraints every time the user opens or closes the the section, so depending on how many times the user does this you'll end up with hundreds of constrains that just aren't needed.

What you should do is set the constraints for the default state, I'm assuming closed in this instance, and store the constraint you wish to change in a property. You can then simply adjust the constant of this constraint to show/hide your menu.

e.g.

```
private var myListCVLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(bgImageView)

    self.configMyListCV()
}

lazy var myListCV: UICollectionView = {

    let myListLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    myListLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)
    myListLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    myListLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

    let myListView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: myListLayout)
    myListView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myListView.delegate = self
    myListView.dataSource = self

    myListView.bounces = false
    myListView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    myListView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    myListView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 203, g: 203, b: 203)

    return myListView
}()

var menuShowing = false

private func configMyListCV() -> Void {

    view.addSubview(myListCV)

    self.myListCV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 64).isActive = true
    self.myListCV.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    self.myListCV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    self.myListCVLeftConstraint = myListCV.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
    self.myListCVLeftConstraint.isActive = true
}

func openMenu() {

    if (menuShowing) {

        self.myListCVLeftConstraint?.constant = 0.0

    } else {

        self.myListCVLeftConstraint?.constant = -200.0

    }

    menuShowing = !menuShowing
}
```

This will work well for this simple user case; however if you do anything more in depth in the future I'd suggest setting multiple constraints on the view and simply disable/enable the required ones as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.  This works like a charm and much appreciated.  I take note of your advice regarding enable/disable of the constraints if I ever want to do anything more complex.

Comment: Awesome. Saved a lot of my time.